# Slick slider interfering with other scripts

Tags: javascript, slick.js

How do I make the Slick library not interfere with other JavaScript files? I know with jQuery there is no conflict; is there something similar with Slick?

Please see the script source: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js

and the link where I'm trying to host it: http://www.zadroinc.com/this-is-a-test

Comment: what is it interfering with?

Comment: What kind of "interference"? What are the symptoms? What's it interfering with?